# UICollectionViewCell unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a UICollectionViewCell that looks like this

```
#import "PhotoCell.h"


@implementation PhotoCell

@synthesize imageView;

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.origin = CGPointMake(4.0f, 4.0f), .size=CGRectInset(frame, 4.0f, 4.0f).size}];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am calling this from one of my view controllers where I am trying to set up a UICollectionView.. this is where I am calling this class

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[self.photoCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];

    // but I have no idea where to pass the imag....

    cell.imageView.image = imageForCollection;

    return cell;
}
```

The issue is, I am getting this error then my app falls over in a heap.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16dc1a90'
```

### Update

I have created a .nib file call aPhotoCell and I have deleted the UIView from it and added a UIImageView. I have then changed the objects Custom Class to PhotoCell and now that I can see the IBOutlet of UIImageView from PhotoCell I have hooked that up, but still I am receiving the same error. From the comments and answers below, this is what I thought I had to do to fix.

Comment: seems like the delegate method -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath    is not returning PhotoCell object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things..

In your `PhotoCell` class - declare a public property:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Then in your `PhotoCell xib` (I assume this is where you're creating it from?) connect it to the `IBOutLet` you created.

I think you're doing something wrong in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` - as your error shows an instance of `UICollectionViewCell` doesn't respond to `cell.imageView.image = imageForCollection;`

Make sure your cell identifier is also the same as you put it in your storyboard / xib file
Rewrite your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{
PhotoCell *cell = [ self.photoCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CORRECT CELL IDENTIFIER HERE" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];


cell.imageView.image = imageForCollection;

return cell;
}
```

**Edit**

It seems like you created a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` and never created a `xib` file for it. Since you're not using storyboards do this:

In Xcode:

Create a new file - select "`User Interface`" from the left under '`iOS'` and select `"empty"` from the selection it shows you.

After creating your `xib` file - go to it and delete `UIView` that is there. Then from the object library on your right, look for `UICollectionView Cell` and drag it onto the view and then drag a `UIImageView` and place it in your `UICollectionView cell.`

Now select `UICollectionViewCell` you just created and set its class to the `PhotoCell` class. Connect your `IBOutlets` like above. 
Make sure to set the '`Reusable Cell`' attribute too. Its important here.

Then in the `viewController` that loads your `UICollectionView` - add this to `viewDidLoad`

```
        [photoCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"THE XIB FILE NAME YOU JUST CREATED eg: PhotoCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"REUSE IDENTIFIER HERE"];
```

This should help you.

Comment: I dont have a story board or nib for this class.. when I created it i was not give an option to make one with it.. Im not really sure how to proceed with that.

Comment: thanks.. the thing is I have tried creating an xib then connecting it using custom class and connecting the IBOutlet but I still recive the same error.

Comment: CHAMP!!! thanks a MEGATON! lol so I was almost there instead of using a UICollectionViewCell then adding the Imageview I was just trying to do it with the imageview! this worked perfectly!!! thnks a ton seriouslY! been banging my head against the wall! again many thanks! lol

Answer (score 4):

I also had this problem and my issue was that I had an error in my code in another place.

I used this code to register the the UICollectionViewCell in the viewDidLoad method.

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseLabel"];
```

However, when I tried to update the cell with my custom UICollectionViewCell I didn't change this line to work my custom cell. So I changed the code to this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"reuseLabel"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html),
   `CollectionViewCell` just didn't have `imageView` property. You should add it to cell's `contentView` in Storyboard / in code first.
2. Also, You're using own `PhotoCell` class. Check that your cell have correct class name in Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the cell identified by "cell" is defined in a Xib file. If so, I suspect that the error is because the main view in the Xib file is defined with the `UICollectionViewCell` class instead of your custom `PhotoCell` class.

EDIT:
After learning that you're not using xib or storyboards, what happens is that `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` doesn't find any cell with the given identifier "cell" becouse you haven't defined it anywhere. From the documentation:

> You must register a class or nib file using the
>   `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:` or
>   `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method before calling this
>   method.

In your case you should use `registerClass:...` to register your class with the "cell" or any other identifier.

Comment: I dont have an xib file for this class as UICOllectionViewCell's dont have xibs when you create them.. nore do they allow you to add them so i dont know what to do??

Answer (score 0):

PhotoCell xib file need set "cell" in Identifier
Your code should be:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    PhotoCell *cell = (PhotoCell *)[self.photoCollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
      // Load the top-level objects from the custom cell XIB.
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"cell" owner:self options:nil];
    // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
    cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSDictionary *currentPhotoDict = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *imageForCollection = [UIImage imageWithData:[currentPhotoDict objectForKey:@"DImage"]];

    // but I have no idea where to pass the imag....

    cell.imageView.image = imageForCollection;

    return cell;
```

}

Comment: I have now created a nib file changes its customclass to PhotoCell and hooked up the UIImageView IBOutlet I made. and still I recive the same error... I am looking for more ideas now.